# While using life cycle manager the disable operation is going in pending disabled state

Tags: rest, web-services, sailpoint

We have a WebService connector with multiples operations setup (GetObject for an account, Enable, Disable, ... create, update, ...).

Theses operation work as expected.

When we try to disable or enable a user account (`Manage Access > Manage Accounts > User selection > Enable/Disable`), IIQ perform an Update Account Operation with a correct payload. "Action Status" is set to "Pending Enable....". Immediately after that, IIQ perform a GetObject Operation through the WebService connector on the user account, and recover the new version of the user with updated values. "Status" is correctly set to "Active", but "Action Status" stay on "Pending Enable..." and we don't know why.

Even if we try to refresh user info (), IIQ perform a GetObject operation on the WebService, but still didn't remove the "pending..." action status

also running "perform Idnetity Request maintainance" the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have set `Schema Attribute for Account Enable status` Attribute value in the configuration to `<AttributeName>=<Active value>`
e.g. only setting variable doesn't make it Disable/Active.

```
accountStatus=Active
```

In this case all values apart from Active will be treated as inactive.